# How to combine lot of packages to one custom style package?

Tags: packages

I write

```
{\documentclass[10pt]{report}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[pdftex,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{bluegreen}{rgb}{0,.3,2}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge}
  {\hspace*{-70pt}\thechapter.~#1}
  {-15pt}
  {\hspace*{-110pt}\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth+30pt\relax}{1pt}}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont}
  {\hspace*{-70pt}#1}
  {-15pt}
  {\hspace*{-110pt}\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth+30pt\relax}{0pt}}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{30pt}    

\geometry{
top=10mm,
total={145mm,230mm}
}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=bluegreen,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
    pdftitle={Sharelatex Example},
    bookmarks=true,
    pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
}

\tikzset{>=stealth}
}
```

everytime i start a LateX document is there anyway to combine them into one package?

Comment: Making an one `.sty` file importing with `\usepackage{...}` and other stuff, without the `\documentclass` of course?  -- The `{\documentclass...` troubles me,however

Comment: How to make one .sty file?

Comment: hopefully you don't really have the `{` at the start? `{\documentclass..` ? Just take all the lines between `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}` put in `foo.sty` then use `\usepackage{foo}`

Comment: why do you load `lipsum` ???

Comment: I include lot of random packages just in case i need

Comment: @DavidCarlisle where do i store this .sty file?

Comment: @bgr95 but hopefully you _never_ need lipsum in a real document.

Comment: @bgr95 anywhere in your input tree: just put it in the same directory as your document initially, till you get it working

Comment: @bgr95 including lots of packages you do not use is generally a bad idea. It has all the problems of slowing things down and risking weird errors due to package interactions, for no gain. Much better to just add packages as you need them.

Comment: Some of those packages can be problematic loaded this way unless you understand what you are doing. If you later decide that, say, you want to use `svgnames` for `xcolor`, you will not be able to say `\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}`unless you do this before loading your saved code. This can get confusing quite quickly. (I actually do this for some of these packages, but I know why I'm getting errors and what to do about them. Don't be offended, but I suspect you do not.)

Answer (score 7):

Short way:

Make a file named, say `mypackages.tex` and copy all the `\usepackage{...}` statements and other stuff into that one.

In your real document use `\documentclass[10pt]{report}` and `\input{mypackages}` before `\begin{document}...\end{document}`

Longer way:

Make a file named `mypackages.sty` with this content:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mypackages}

\RequirePackage{foo}
\RequirePackage{bar}

% Other stuff from your frequent used files

\endinput
```

Place this file either in your local working directory or in a local `texmf` directory (depends on the distribution/operating system)

In your real document you can use

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage{mypackages}

\begin{document}
....
\end{document}
```

In all cases replace `\documentclass[10pt]{report}` by the real settings -- it's only an example here!

Comment: `\documentclass{yourclass}`: Do you mean `<whatever class you are using>` or a custom class? At present it might be a bit confusing whether the instructions show how to make a `.sty` package or a `.cls` class.

Comment: @AndrewCashner: Good point, thanks -- I changed it to the class mentioned in the post

Comment: I don't have `\NeedsTeXFormat` in any of my packages…

Comment: @clemens: Your packages do not comply to any standard: They are outstanding :-P

Comment: I wanted to do this: Since I use windows I created a folder C:\Users\xyz\texmf\tex\latex where I saved my .sty file and everything works

Comment: @user44342: Yes? Did you say this in your question?