# ShareLaTeX - Avoid changing main document when using the input command

Tags: compiling, sharelatex

In ShareLaTeX when I write a single document with the preamble in it, then no matter which is the main document I just press compile and the output is produced.

On the other hand when I place the preamble in a separate file and use the `\input` command then I have to set that document as the main one in order to compile it successfully.

I can't understand why is that necessary. Is there a way to avoid changing the main document every time, even though I am using a separate preamble file?

Comment: The 'that' in your second paragraph has an unclear antecedent. Is it the file being `\input`-ed or the main file that has the `\input` command in it? And I have to wonder whether Share LaTeX has a help section because I would imagine that many sophisticated editors -- even Emacs! -- wants you to set the 'main' document if you are going to compile from an included/subsidiary file.

Comment: @jon the `\input` command is in the document that the preamble will be imported. I don't know if I understood correct what you re saying so feel free to ask me to clarify further. This question is more about why in the first case I don't have to set a main document yet in the second I have.

Comment: I know where the `\input` command would have to be: but from which document are you compiling?  I also suggest *not* using `\input` in this way, but `\usepackage`. The structure is `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{mypreamble} \begin{document} text \end{document}`. If you are doing `\input{mypreamble} \begin{document} text \end{document}`, then the best advice is: don't. If you are trying to compile from 'within' `mypreamble`, then I'd assume you'd need to inform any reasonable editor that you are not in the 'main' document.

Comment: Also: if you want to separate text and 'code', the best structure is to create a 'shell' file and a 'content' file. So: `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{mypreamble} \begin{document} \input{content} \end{document}` where `content.tex` is the file that contains the text that will be typeself. Again, however, I think `content.tex` will (and should) have a flag marking which file is the 'master'.

Comment: @jon I don't compile from the preamble. I found in the ShareLaTeX's documentation that creating a package with the preamble (as you propose yourself) is the best solution so I started using this one and indeed is great but I am just trying to understand why it doesn't compile in the second case.

Comment: Whic one is the second case? If it's the one that does not have `\documentclass` as the first line but `\input{mypreamble}`, I'd presume that ShareLaTeX parses the file by looking for `\documentclass` and if it can't find it, it presumes that it is not actually the 'master file' (but that is a guess: I have never used ShareLaTeX). As I said, that kind of set up is not good practice. Use either of the other two I mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you to separate your preambles from the 'body' of their document, you might think this is a good idea: create a preamble (say, `preamble.tex`) and their main file (say, `main.tex`).  For example,

```
% preamble.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand\myname{XXXX YYYYY}
```

and then use it in:

```
% main.tex
\input{preamble}
\begin{document}

My name is \myname.

\end{document}
```

My advice is: **do not do this**. I understand the temptation to separate out the two 'parts', especially if it is a long document, etc.  However, if you want to separate the parts, there is a better way to do it:

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand*{\myname}{XXXX YYYY}
% ... other preamble stuff
\begin{document}

\input{content}
% or \include{content}, though there are differences between the two;
% see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/8528

\end{document}
```

And then you do your 'writing' in `content.tex`

```
% content.tex
My name is \myname.
```

Note that you might have to 'flag' this as a subsidiary file and point it to the 'master'.  Every editor probably does this differently. In Emacs it is easy. At the bottom of your file, you put:

```
%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex  
%%% TeX-master: "main"  
%%% End:
```

(Really, only the `%%% TeX-master: "main"` is doing the relevant work here.)

Although I cannot speak about ShareLaTeX, which I have never used, it is entirely possible that if it cannot see the line `\documentclass` it will assume that it is not actually a file that can be processed by LaTeX. (This would be another reason to avoid the first method I described above and which I strongly encourage people to avoid.) Presumably the website allows you to mark 'main' and 'subsidiary' files in the way (e.g.) Emacs does, but I do not know how it does....

This method also allows you to rely on a common preamble. If you are going to do this, then it is best to name it with the `.sty` extension and load it via `\usepackage`. For more information on how to do this, see:

- [How to maintain macros file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/279714/8528)
- [How to combine lot of packages to one custom style package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/273862/8528)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your suggestion is great although I placed my preamble in a `.sty` file and I use it with a `usepackage` command, but my main question is why I need to set a main document when I use the `input` command? When I compile your example without setting it as a main document then everything works fine so from what I see is that you must have the `documentclass` and the `begin{document}/end{document}`commands in the file that you compile. If that is the case add it to your answer to be full.

Comment: On a sidenote do you believe that is better to use your solution for the `input` or the solution when the the preamble is in a `.sty` file?

Comment: If you have a 'common preamble', then i'd ues the `main.tex` file as described above in the 'better way' and just use `\usepackage{mypreamble}`. So: `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{mypreamble} \begin{document} \input{content} \end{document}`. That means you have three files: `preamble.sty`, `main.tex`, and `content.tex`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I only want to get the preamble out of the way so the `input` command is not really necessary for me, but it is still a great way.